# How to only access seccond parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, parameters

I'm create a function and assigned two-parameter  **But**
For this assigned two-argument.
I want to control one parameter right side [`para2`]

```
let veri=2;
function school(para1,para2)     // if para2 accept 
{
    para2=Math.floor(Math.random()*para2); //so :- 0 or 1
    return para2;
}
veri=school(veri);     // ! This veri pass arg second parameter
 if(veri){
   console.log('Time is playing cricket');
 }else{
   console.log('study time...');
 }
```

We have to pass two arguments for two parameters
I want that only one argument should be passed and only the right side can be controlled.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please add some details, your error and desired behaviour. Consider reading [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things you should pay attention to is the "syntax" of a programming language (Or frankly, any programming language).

When you are defining a function, or essentially a block of code with a specific scope, a name and parameters, you are basically saying how it should work and what it should do.
Hence, defining a function with two parameters, you should consider the first parameter as well. Because you have defined it as such.

Now there are many ways to approaching this.

You can either give it a meaningless value:

```
school(undefined, veri)
// OR
school(0, veri)
// OR
school('Nothing to do here', veri)
```

Or inside the body of the function define distinct values that the function will not act upon.

But because there is a second parameter, you can't neglect it when you're calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you can pass `undefined` as the first arg, e.g.

```
school(undefined, veri)
```

Comment: saying that, your current implementation of `school` doesnt use `para1` at all, so not sure why it needs to be in the function signature at all

Answer (score 0):

To skip parameter 1, pass in `undefined`

```js
veri=school(undefined, veri);
```